# Is there a way to group all Activities in one window and all xml files in another window in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any IntelliJ/Android Studio function to be able to group files based on their type like this?

Answer (score 0):

No, and why would you want that anyway? Android Studio arranges files perfectly, and you have multiple ways to look at the files:

[image]

But, you can keep multiple tabs open and drag them around to have the XML's on the left, and the .java files on the right, or the XML's on the right, and the .java files on the left:

[image]

So to answer your question, no, but you can look through different views, and change your tab views. Why would you want to have separate windows anyway, there would be the hassle of switching between them.

Comment: Well I'm working with multiple monitors and I'm looking at 12 tabs on 3 rows and since I have 2 Android Studio coding windows open, it would just be better organized for me to have all my XMLs on 1 screen and my Java files on the other

Comment: @EddieLee I see what you're saying. What you can do is go into project view and edit the notepad document for the java in a separate window...that'd be your only option. Anyway, if you found my answer useful, make sure to click the checkmark to accept it. Feel free to ask any more questions, I am happy to help!

Comment: Sure, I'd just like to make sure to see if anyone else has any other insights - otherwise I'll be accepting yours as the best alternative :)